# Android app shows white screen except for new install

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on an Android app with Android Studio using Kotlin. The app was working fine until yesterday when it started showing white screen when I relaunch the app.

If I delete the app from the emulator and run the app, it installs and works perfectly fine. 
But if I stop the app and relaunch either from Android Studio or from within the emulator, all I see is a white screen.

I am using Pixel 3a XL API 28 virtual device. 
I allocated 512 MB VM Heap, and 1 GB Internal Storage. The app itself occupies only 35 MB.

I setup Log statements in MainActivity onCreate, onStart, onResume methods. None of them execute during the relaunches. They run only on the new install.

Has anyone seen this problem?
Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: you can try recreate virtual device. I also recently encounter the same problem, when i open my project, android studio keep crashing. I reinstall the android studio and recreate virtual devices and it works perfectly fine now.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have some code that is making it impossible to create the first screen again? Double check everything in the onCreate and onResume functions of your MainActivity.kt. It could be that the application will not load a second time due to an infinite loop or similar.

Comment: I haven't touched the mainactivity in a while. But the infinite loop or similar issue might be happening. Even so, I would assume that main activity would start back up at least. If I don't see any obvious solution, I am thinking of starting a new app from the scratch and adding the copying the code piece by piece and see what broke it. I will wait for a couple of days and do that.

Comment: @phonemyatt - reinstalling android studio and recreating virtual device didn't work either.

Comment: I think the emulator must be hanged ...is the same problem repeating in the physical device?

Comment: did you test this on real device?

Comment: @KishoreChalla can you try to open android studio without internet connection? and do you also reinstall android sdk? check whether android sdk has up to date api level and revision verson.

Answer (score 1):

please add this line into your app theme

```
<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
```

Comment: The problem with white background is caused because of android's cold start while the app loads to memory

Answer (score 0):

[Instant Run in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TU7zd.jpg)sometimes issue when running app while white screen appears to try to disable Instant Run in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem with the emulator, try running the app on a physical android device.

If the contents in your app requires internet then also check whether you internet 
is on or not, sometimes white screen can occur due to no internet also if your app requires active internet connection.